# Stackoverflow error when writing larger size object to a file

Tags: java

When I give a smaller size input file, there is no error. But when giving an input file of a larger size, I am getting an error. I'm creating a tree object for that input file, and I then want to save the object to the file. The file will be created and when it writes later, it's giving an error.

Does anybody know how to write a larger object to a file using 
`ObjectOutputStream`?

```
try{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"in try");
  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("d://obj.ser");
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"obj created");
  ObjectOutputStream foos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);  
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"oos created");  //till here i get output

  foos.writeObject(tree);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"here compltes writeobj");
  foos.flush();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"after flush");
  //foos.close();
  fout.close();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"alll");


}catch(Exception ex){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error");
}
```

Tree file is :

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    /**
         * This is an implementation of a MISTree (which is modified from a fptree).
    * 
    * 
    */
        public class MISTree implements Serializable {
       // List of items in the header table
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 5950169519310163575L;
       List<Integer> headerList = null;
      // List of pairs (item, node) of the header table
     Map<Integer, MISNode> mapItemNodes = new HashMap<Integer, MISNode>();

      // root of the tree
        MISNode root = new MISNode(); // null node

      /**
       * Constructor
        */
       MISTree() {

       }

    /**
        * Method for adding a transaction to the fp-tree (for the initial
       * construction of the FP-Tree).
       * 
      * @param transaction
    */
      public void addTransaction(List<Integer> transaction) {
     MISNode currentNode = root;
      // For each item in the transaction
    for (Integer item : transaction) {
                    // System.out.println("item in this transaction is "+item);
        // look if there is a node already in the FP-Tree
        MISNode child = currentNode.getChildWithID(item);
        if (child == null) {
            // there is no node, we create a new one
             MISNode newNode = new MISNode();
            newNode.itemID = item;
            newNode.parent = currentNode;
             // we link the new node to its parrent
            currentNode.childs.add(newNode);

             // we take this node as the current node for the next for loop
            // iteration
            currentNode = newNode;

            // We update the header table.
             // We check if there is already a node with this id in the
            // header table
            MISNode headernode = mapItemNodes.get(item);
            if (headernode == null) { // there is not
                mapItemNodes.put(item, newNode);
             } else { // there is
                    // we find the last node with this  id.
                while (headernode.nodeLink != null) {
                    headernode = headernode.nodeLink;
                }
                headernode.nodeLink = newNode;
            }
        } else {
            // there is a node already, we update it
            child.counter++;
            currentNode = child;
         }
    }
}

// here some other methods like to print a tree and other are there
 }
```

MIS Node also serialized.
And it works fine for smaller tree. no error but for larger size tree its giving an error

Error is like this:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: so you get until before `foos.write...`? what is `tree`?

Comment: What is `tree`? And what error do you get?

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781786/2542027

Comment: If you do serialisation yourself, and tree would have a node being its own ancestor, then such a thing might happen. Maybe the stacktrace shows something? Also mind that an internal class being serialized takes its surrounding class with it.

Comment: @Tichodroma `StackOverflowError`

Comment: ha sir will get output if tree is small if its bigger size will get till before foos.write...

Comment: and even for larger file file will be created and it writes but in between this error comes (when i check file size while running prg that file size changes till 30kb) later error i m getting sir

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling the issue is your tree structure. `ObjectOutputStream` works by serializing the objects, and when serializing an object all members of that object will themselves be serialized by default (leaving aside certain edge cases), which means if you have a deeply-nested tree, each level in the tree will mean more calls to the serialization functions. (I don't think cyclic references would be part of the problem, as Java's serializer keeps track of backreferences, but that may only work for already-serialized objects rather than objects in the process of being serialized so you may want to check on that too.)

I would suggest flattening out the tree in some fashion and writing the objects individually rather than trying to write the entire tree as one object. Then, when you read the objects in with an `ObjectInputStream`, rebuild the tree from the flattened objects.

Comment: ... or check the `tree` for cycles. That would kill the serialization too.

Comment: @Andreas_D Last I checked, Java does okay when serializing cyclic references. (I haven't done much serialization of interconnected objects recently so I can't say for sure, though.)